# Filling value in web browser thru asp.net

Tags: asp.net, axwebbrowser

I have a requirement of filling a text box in open web browser page through asp.net/vb.net application.
My website1 will be opened first by user then he will open another website2. I have to push a value in textbox in website2 from website1.

How can we do this.

Pls help.

Comment: "I have a requirement" - you have an impossible requirement.

Comment: "How can we do this." - **you can't**. Client-scripts in one browser tab/page/window cannot access other browser tabs/pages/windows. There are exceptions for same-origin sites opened as a child from within another, but that's it.

Comment: In a simple macro in excel it is possible using Shell.Windows(VBA). It loops through open windows and returns a particular webpage as an HTML document where we can set values.The only limitation is that it works in IE only. In here i will get a value from my database which i have to fill in the form.

Comment: Yes, but that's a completely different use-case: that's when the browser user-agent is directly scripted from within a desktop environment. Normal web-browsers don't allow that, and there is no way for a remotely hosted web-application to directly control a visitor's web-browser for what should be obvious reasons.

Comment: OK, I will connect to my SQL from VBA itself and do the rest. Thanks anyways @Dai

Comment: Your web page and site can't mess with say me having open my banking web site on another page - it would be a security hole far too large.  You think when you come to my site to view a cat picture, that site can now going messing around in YOUR computer and steal files without you knowing? Or grab control of other web page like your banking site you have open? Nope, it not allowed.  This type of setup and security is by design, and if it was not the case, then no one would risk using the internet.